# Meteor - rendering the name of the owner in a list objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm getting an object not found error when I try and lookup the owner of the objects 
i'm trying to render. I'm looping through a collection of video clips, that can be updated or administered by users. The code works fine when I'm logged in, but when I try to use this and I'm logged out, I get "Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined at Object.Template.video_info.creatorName "

I've tried to debug this by doing this:

```
console.log(this.owner);
var owner = Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner);
console.log(owner);
```

When I check the console log, I can see that the correct userid is being found, and when i manually run Meteor.users.findOne with this id I get a user object returned. Is there something strange about the timings in Meteor that is preventing this?

UPDATE: If I add a try...catch to the template creatorname function then 2 errors get logged but the template still renders... ??? Seems like this template is being called twice, one when it's not ready, and again once it is. Why would that be.

Example of the try...catch block:

```
  Template.video_info.creatorName = function () {
      try{
        var owner = Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner);
        if (owner._id === Meteor.userId())
          return "me";
        return displayName(owner);
      } catch (e){
        console.log(e);
      }
  };
```

ORIGINAL BROKEN CODE BELOW THIS POINT

This is in my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    {{> video_list}}
  </div>
</body>
<template name="video_list">
  <h1>Video List</h1>
  {{#each videos}}
    <ul>
      {{> video_info}}
    </ul>
  {{else}}
    No videos yet.
  {{/each}}
  <div class="footer">
    <button>Like!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="video_info">
  <li class="video-list {{maybe_selected}}">
    <img src="{{image}}" />
    <div>
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
      <h4>{{creatorName}}</h4>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

This is in my client.js

```
Meteor.subscribe("videos");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.video_list.videos = function() {
    return Videos.find({}, {sort: {title: 1}});
  };

  Template.video_list.events = {
    'click button': function(){
      Videos.update(Session.get('session_video'),{$inc: {likes: 1}});
    }
  }

  Template.video_info.maybe_selected = function() {
    return Session.equals('session_video', this._id) ? "selected" : "";
  }

  Template.video_info.events = {
    'click': function(){
      Session.set('session_video', this._id);
    }
  }

  Template.video_info.creatorName = function () {
    var owner = Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner);
    if (owner._id === Meteor.userId())
      return "me";
    return displayName(owner);
  };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

This is in my model.js

```
Videos = new Meteor.Collection("videos");

Videos.allow({
  insert: function (userId, video) {
    return false; // no cowboy inserts -- use createParty method
  },
  update: function (userId, video, fields, modifier) {
    if (userId !== video.owner)
      return false; // not the owner

    var allowed = ["title", "description", "videoid", "image", "start"];
    if (_.difference(fields, allowed).length)
      return false; // tried to write to forbidden field

    // A good improvement would be to validate the type of the new
    // value of the field (and if a string, the length.) In the
    // future Meteor will have a schema system to makes that easier.
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, video) {
    // You can only remove parties that you created and nobody is going to.
    return video.owner === userId; //&& attending(video) === 0;
  }
});

var NonEmptyString = Match.Where(function (x) {
  check(x, String);
  return x.length !== 0;
});

var NonEmptyNumber = Match.Where(function (x) {
  check(x, Number);
  return x.length !== 0;
});

createVideo = function (options) {
  var id = Random.id();
  Meteor.call('createVideo', _.extend({ _id: id }, options));
  return id;
};

Meteor.methods({
  // options should include: title, description, x, y, public
  createVideo: function (options) {
    check(options, {
      title: NonEmptyString,
      description: NonEmptyString,
      videoid: NonEmptyString,
      image:NonEmptyString,
      start: NonEmptyNumber,
      _id: Match.Optional(NonEmptyString)
    });

    if (options.title.length > 100)
      throw new Meteor.Error(413, "Title too long");
    if (options.description.length > 1000)
      throw new Meteor.Error(413, "Description too long");
    if (! this.userId)
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You must be logged in");

    var id = options._id || Random.id();
    Videos.insert({
      _id: id,
      owner: this.userId,
      videoid: options.videoid,
      image: options.image,
      start: options.start,
      title: options.title,
      description: options.description,
      public: !! options.public,
      invited: [],
      rsvps: []
    });
    return id;
  },

});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Users

displayName = function (user) {
  if (user.profile && user.profile.name)
    return user.profile.name;
  return user.emails[0].address;
};

var contactEmail = function (user) {
  if (user.emails && user.emails.length)
    return user.emails[0].address;
  if (user.services && user.services.facebook && user.services.facebook.email)
    return user.services.facebook.email;
  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the solution to this one. After reading about the caching works in Meteor, I've discovered the subscription model and how this relates to meteors minimongo http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity. The reason this was failing then succeeding was that on the first load the data is still being cached in minimongo. I'm currently checking against Accounts login Services Configured to check if the user data has been loaded. I'm currently using this because I can't find a way to subscribe to the Metor users service, but my guess is that the Accounts login service would rely on the Metor users collection. My current solution looks like this:

```
if(Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()){
  var owner = Meteor.users.findOne(this.owner);
  if (owner._id === Meteor.userId())
    return "me";
  return displayName(owner);
}
```

Currently this appears to be working correctly. I'm still delving into how to subscribe to this users service.Couple of really userful resferences I found while searching for a solution for this

- https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq
- http://psychopyko.com/cool-stuff/meteor-6-simple-tips/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/QKXe7qfBfqg

Answer (score 0):

The app might not be publishing the user id to the client when you are logged out. You can try calling the find method on the server and return the user. Or use a different key for querying/

Comment: Definately pushing out the user ID. I'm using it to identify a list of objects (so there will be multiple user ids). And it runs if I wrap it in a try...catch block. I think it has something to do with the timing of the operation.