# Data not accessible in helper block in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have autopublish on.

```
Template.play.helpers ({
   title: function () {
  wcount = Workouts.find().count();
  console.log(wcount);
   }
});
```

This gives me 0.

But if I'm in the developer console of my browser.

```
Workouts.find().count()
24
```

I have recently upgraded to 0.8

If I add waitOn to the Router then I get this behavior every other time I load the page.

```
Router.map(function() {
this.route('splash', {path: '/'});
this.route('play', { 
path: '/play',
template: 'play',
waitOn: function() { 
    return Meteor.subscribe('Workouts')
}
});
```

After some help from @Christian Fritz it seems that my problem is that its not waiting on my subscription and if the helper doesn't return anything because its undefined then it doesn't get rerun when the data does get loaded.

I have now turned off autopublish.  My server/publications.js is:

```
Meteor.publish('workouts', function() {
   return Workouts.find();
});
```

My router is:

```
Router.configure({
     layoutTemplate: 'layout',
     loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

 Router.map(function() {
    this.route('splash', {path: '/'});
    this.route('play', { 
   path: '/play',
   template: 'play',
   waitOn: function() { 
     return Meteor.subscribe('workouts')
  }
    });
});
```

in play.js

```
var workoutsSubcription = Meteor.subscribe('workouts');
console.log("workoutsSubscription.ready() is ",workoutsSubcription.ready());
```

returns:
    workoutsSubscription.ready() is  false

once or twice then finally reruns when its fully loaded as true.  But shouldn't the waitOn mean that it doesn't run that page until the data is there?

Comment: Most probably the call that is giving you 0 is executed before the collection has synced completely. Can you show the code where it is being used? If you make it part of a reactive block it should be re-run once the data is there and then return 24.

Comment: Thanks. I added a waitOn but that didn't solve the problem. how do I make it part of a reactive block?

Comment: I think `waitOn` only makes sense in routes, not in the general `Router` config. Can you show the code where you define your route?

Comment: Yes, I think that you were right that was a problem, I changed it to below but I'm still getting errors every other reload.
'Router.map(function() {
    this.route('splash', {path: '/'});
    this.route('play', { 
 path: '/play',
 template: 'play',
 waitOn: function() { 
     return Meteor.subscribe('Workouts')
 }
    });'
});

Comment: What happens when you actually add a return statement to your helper? Without that, Meteor might be too smart and may not rerun the helper function when the data arrives (because no DOM node actually depends on it).

Comment: Thanks Christian, adding return wcount causes it to rerun. I had return thisStep.title and that undefined so when the data reloaded it didn't know to rerun. But I'm still confused as to why my waitOn doesn't cause the page to wait to run in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
var workoutsSubcription = Meteor.subscribe('workout_count');

Template.play.helpers ({
   title: function () {
     if(workoutsSubcription.ready()){
       wcount = Workouts.find().count();
     }
   }
});
```

You would need to publish your subscription on the server as well

```
Meteor.publish("workout_count", function () {
  return Workouts.find();
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I just tried adding the var workoutsSubscription and  console.log(workoutsSubcription.ready());

It is consistently false even as wcount switches between 0 and 24 every other reload.

Comment: Added a server side subcription example. Try that, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893033/meteor-rendering-the-name-of-the-owner-in-a-list-objects for some references